# Struct Array in secondVC not being appended from the firstVC

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have created a struct and made an array of that type. The struct consists of two variable:

```
struct notesarray
{
    var prioritycolor : UIColor
    var note : String
}
```

In my secondVC which houses a collectionViewController, I have made an array of type notesarray. I am sending values for prioritycolor and note from firstVC.

I will be setting up CoreData later on, for now I just want this to work in simplest of manners. I am appending data from firstVC to this array like so:

```
@objc func handleCheckButton()
{
    print("Added")
    let secondVC = AddedNotesCollectionViewController()

    secondVC.allnotes.append(notesarray(prioritycolor: taskTextView.backgroundColor!, note: taskTextView.text))
    print(secondVC.allnotes.count)

    taskTextView.text = nil

}
```

allnotes is the name of the array found in secondVC.

For testing purposes I am printing `secondVC.allnotes.count` but I am just getting '1' in console no matter how many time I add elements to the array. 
I have also tested this by placing `print(allnotes.count)` under `viewDidAppear` func in secondVC so that whenever I go to secondVC it gives me count of the elements in the array but it also shows '0' every time.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you end up getting a new instance of `AddedNotesCollectionViewController` every time you press the button.

```
let secondVC = AddedNotesCollectionViewController()
```

And new instance is initiated with an empty array and you add one element to it by calling

```
secondVC.allnotes.append(notesarray(prioritycolor: taskTextView.backgroundColor!, note: taskTextView.text))
```

Hence count is always one. iOS is correct there my friend :)

**What you need:**

If second VC is already loaded either by pushing a it on to navigation stack of FirstVC or if its presented then get the reference to the presented/pushed VC rather than creating a new one every time. There are many answers in SO which explains how to access the pushed/modally presented VC :)

If you are about to present/push the SecondVC, as you mentioned in the comments you can always make use of `prepareForSegue` to pass the data.

If in case your `AddedNotesCollectionViewController` is never presented then rather consider creating `singleton instance` of `notesArray` which you will share between multiple VCs.

Hope it helps

Comment: @osama-naeem : One word : Bingo!!! but that being said there are multiple ways to pass data between VCs you can choose the one that suites you better :) I would go for segue  hence I said Bingo

Comment: Thank you so much Sandeep! Will get on it and get back to you :) Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Sandeep-Bhandari, Just wanted to ask if you could help me. I am resizing my collectionviewcells dynamically but when I delete a particular cell, the remaining cells' content get off. Here is a detailed post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235608/cell-layout-refresh-after-deleting-one-cell-in-uicollectionview 
any idea what's going wrong here?